Nest Js Authentification
I have implemented authentication with JWT in NestJS without using Passport, as I find it easier for solo development. I'm still new to NestJS and have a question about implementing refresh tokens. Currently, when a user logs in, I generate two tokens: one with a short expiration time (5 minutes) for regular usage, and another refresh token with a longer expiration (for example, one week) to use for generating new access tokens when the first one expires. However, I'm unsure if this approach is optimal, or if there's a better way to handle refresh tokens in NestJS.
I try already auth but i wonder if my logic is correct

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

There is not optimal solution for it. One would say short tokens for interacting with page, and long living tokens for refreshing ot access tokens. One solution would prefer usage of both token being long lived. Depends on what you require from application and the usage of it. If the timings you got works for the project - then they are good.

Just like how every Authentication works , you get an accessToken and refreshToken . So it logical . And yes ,next auth provides a way to implement your refresh Token logic ,  can you provide some clarity with your implementation code, that will be helpful to help you out .

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
